# How to convert WP post_content to json Object based on tag type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to convert the content of a post to a json object depending on the tags/blocks used while generating a blog post or a page.

This is the WordPress post_content sample code.

```
"<!-- wp:image {"id":19,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="https://neu-api.amit-k.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/pexels-binyamin-mellish-186077-1-1024x698.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-19"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit addmet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget. Ac felis donec et odio. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Sit amet est placerat in egestas. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus. Et molestie ac feugiat sed. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->"
```

I want it to be like this JSON

```
[
   {
      "wp_type":"wp:image",
      "html_content":"<figure class=\"wp-block-image size-large\"><img src=\"https://neu-api.amit-k.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/pexels-binyamin-mellish-186077-1-1024x698.jpg\" alt=\"\" class=\"wp-image-19\"/></figure>",
      "tag_style":"\"id\":19,\"sizeSlug\":\"large\",\"linkDestination\":\"none\""
   },
   {
      "wp_type":"wp:heading",
      "html_content":"<h2>This is heading 2</h2>",
      "tag_style":""
   },
   {
      "wp_type":"wp:paragraph",
      "html_content":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit addmet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget. Ac felis donec et odio. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae.</p>",
      "tag_style":""
   },
   {
      "wp_type":"wp:paragraph",
      "html_content":"<p>Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Sit amet est placerat in egestas. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus. Et molestie ac feugiat sed. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus.</p>",
      "tag_style":""
   }
]
```

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this. I've been wondering the same for a couple years now. Also, why not just store the data as Jason if using postgres? Does it make sense doing up a nosql DB just for post content? So much to unpack here.